# Does homotopy between functions can induce homotopy between their images?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f,g$ be two continuous functions between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. Suppose $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, can we say $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are homotopic?

I think intuitively they are. Because $f\simeq g$ means there exists an $H:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ which is continuous such that $H(x,0)=f(x),H(x,1)=g(x)$. I think it is saying that the image of $f$, namely $f(X)$, can continuously deform into $g(X)$. Then it seems to mean $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are homotopic, by the geometric intuition of homotopy.

But trouble comes when I try to prove it. For this end, I need to construct a map from $f(X)$ to $g(X)$ and a map from $g(X)$ to $f(X)$. However, after some try, I cannot find such map.

Can anyone help?

Comment: *Functions* are homotopic; *spaces* are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, I mean that, sorry for misuse..

Answer (score 3):

No. For example, let $X$ be a two-point discrete space, $Y$ be $\Bbb{R}$, $f$ be constant and $g$ be nonconstant.

Comment: I suddenly realize it and just what to delete this question..anyway, thanks.